# Make all elements in the same row bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a site for my band, and I want a section with images of the members. I am using bootstrap, and I want that these images to be shown in the same line!

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="feature">
                                <figure class="cut-corner">
                                    <img src="dummy/medium-image-2.jpg" alt="">
                                </figure>
                                <h3 class="feature-title">Similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi laborum dolorum</h3>
                                <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident.</p>
                            </div> <!-- .feature -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="feature">
                                <figure class="cut-corner">
                                    <img src="dummy/medium-image-2.jpg" alt="">
                                </figure>
                                <h3 class="feature-title">Similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi laborum dolorum</h3>
                                <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident.</p>
                            </div> <!-- .feature -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="feature">
                                <figure class="cut-corner">
                                    <img src="dummy/medium-image-3.jpg" alt="">
                                </figure>
                                <h3 class="feature-title">Similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi laborum dolorum</h3>
                                <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident.</p>
                            </div> <!-- .feature -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="feature">
                                <figure class="cut-corner">
                                    <img src="dummy/medium-image-3.jpg" alt="">
                                </figure>
                                <h3 class="feature-title">Similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi laborum dolorum</h3>
                                <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident.</p>
                            </div> <!-- .feature -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="feature">
                                <figure class="cut-corner">
                                    <img src="dummy/medium-image-3.jpg" alt="">
                                </figure>
                                <h3 class="feature-title">Similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi laborum dolorum</h3>
                                <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident.</p>
                            </div> <!-- .feature -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And here is the CSS code:

```
.feature {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;

  }
  /* line 238, sass/pages/_homepage.scss */
  .feature figure {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
float: left
    }
    /* line 242, sass/pages/_homepage.scss */
    .feature figure.cut-corner:after {
      content: " ";
      width: 37px;
      height: 37px;
      background: #141414;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -15px;
      right: -18px;

      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
              transform: rotate(45deg); }
    /* line 253, sass/pages/_homepage.scss */
    .feature figure img {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto; }
  /* line 260, sass/pages/_homepage.scss */
  .feature .feature-title {
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    font-weight: 400;
```

}

The problem is: how can I display these images in the same line? I tried a lot of different things, but they still are being divided in columns. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [Media component](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media). I believe it fits what your trying to do, with a lot less code. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are usin "col-md-4", but if you use the original bootstrap without modified, you can not use one "row" with than more 12. The example below is a maximum for one row:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for nested rows?
the only thing i can think of is this :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                something 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                something 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                something 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                something 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                something 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

with 5 col-md-4 divs, you should end up with 1 row of 3 (4 x 3 = 12) and another row of 2. In order to get all 5 in one row, you'll need to use col-md-2 (2 x 5 = 10). 
Try something along these lines... ([see on Codepen](http://codepen.io/EgoPlacebo/pen/obowLm))

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
<div class="feature">
  <figure class="cut-corner">
    <img src="dummy/medium-image-2.jpg" alt="">
  </figure>
  <h3 class="feature-title">Similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi laborum dolorum</h3>
  <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident.</p>
</div> <!-- .feature -->
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="feature">
  <figure class="cut-corner">
    <img src="dummy/medium-image-2.jpg" alt="">
  </figure>
  <h3 class="feature-title">Similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi laborum dolorum</h3>
  <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident.</p>
</div> <!-- .feature -->
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="feature">
  <figure class="cut-corner">
    <img src="dummy/medium-image-3.jpg" alt="">
  </figure>
  <h3 class="feature-title">Similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi laborum dolorum</h3>
  <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident.</p>
</div> <!-- .feature -->
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="feature">
  <figure class="cut-corner">
    <img src="dummy/medium-image-3.jpg" alt="">
  </figure>
  <h3 class="feature-title">Similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi laborum dolorum</h3>
  <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident.</p>
</div> <!-- .feature -->
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="feature">
  <figure class="cut-corner">
    <img src="dummy/medium-image-3.jpg" alt="">
  </figure>
  <h3 class="feature-title">Similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi laborum dolorum</h3>
  <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident.</p>
</div> <!-- .feature -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
```